# Laravel: symlink(): Permission denied on centos how to fix?

Tags: laravel, centos7

I am installing a project made in laravel on a server with a CENTOS 7.9 vmware [cpnael] v94.0.8 operating system, modify the permissions I needed to operate the project.

When I run the project I get the present error:

```
[2021-05-10 16:26:39] production.ERROR: symlink(): Permission denied {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): symlink(): Permission denied at /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:315)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'symlink(): Perm...', '/home/cbdev/pub...', 315, Array)
#1 /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(315): symlink('/home/cbdev/pub...', '/home/cbdev/pub...')
#2 /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/StorageLinkCommand.php(45): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->link('/home/cbdev/pub...', '/home/cbdev/pub...')
#3 /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\StorageLinkCommand->handle()
#4 /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#5 /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#6 /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#7 /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(611): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#8 /home/cbdev/public_html/crater/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

use this command `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

If `php artisan storage:link` does not help, it can happen that your hosting does not allow you to make symlinks with a command.

Try to contact the support of your hosting if this is the case, or try to make the symlink manually using midnight commander (use the command `mc` in the ssh of the webserver then create the symlink between public storage and storage/app/public)  ,
or with the `ln` linux command (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/).